# Ajax call inside $.ajaxSetup, beforeSend - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to make a quick Ajax request to test a value before any other Ajax requests are run within my application. I'd like to avoid having to use `beforeSend` in each unique request, so I've tried using `ajaxSetup`, `ajaxSend` and others.

So far ajaxSetup seems to work great if I'm doing something simple such as logging a test message to the console, but as soon as I introduce the `$.ajax` request below it's causing an error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in the console.

There's only a single Ajax request made when this particular page loads, and only about 5-6 others that are bound to button clicks. But this is occurring as soon as the page loads.

Is it not proper to "nest" Ajax requests like this?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // console.log("inside setup") <-- this will log thousands of messages in the console.
    beforeSend: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo $apiBaseUrl . "/" . $_SESSION['calendar_id'] ?>/crossover",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    showCrossoverPrompt();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 and can't upgrade at this time.

Comment: so, you have a beforeSend handler, that sends an ajax request, that calls the beforeSend handler, that sends an ajax request... do you see the problem now?

Comment: @KevinB I do. I guess I was hoping there might be something under the hood that might prevent the recursion if `beforeSend` was inside `ajaxSetup`, but I get ya. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Easy, add a beforeSend to the nested ajax call to override the default one.

Comment: @KevinB Nice man, should've thought of that. Will give it a try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @KevinB This is working great, thanks for the hint. If you think it's answer-worthy I'll accept it.